# Can I use Game Center logo on my app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, game-center

I'm adding Game Center to my app and I want to put the logo on a screen. Can I do it or it will be rejected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you use any logo, you need to check the restrictions on its use. Normally, logo usage is restricted because it implies the logo owner has approved or authorised your product, which may not be the case.

In the case of Game Center, I would be surprised if Apple didn't create a special banner that could be used for applications, but I wouldn't expect them to allow use of the logo.

Comment: From that discussion, the people at Apple point to the "Getting Started with Game Center" document: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/download.action?path=/ios/getting_started_with_ios_4.1/gettingstartedwithgamecenter.pdf where it is said: "Be sure that your app presents Game Center functionality in a way that is integrated with the game and fits its style. Rather than using the Game Center logo as a label or providing a separate "Game Center" menu item, you should choose terms that present your use of Game Center functionality from the player's perspective."

Comment: I have sent the app this sunday. I added the GC logo so I will tell you if it passed the review or not ;)

Comment: The apps is ready for sale with the logo, no problems from app store.